# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test, during Cucumber testing

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber-jvm, allure

I need to attach Allure to my Cucumber (Java) test project.

In fact, all tests that I've got, run correctly if I start them from JUnit test-starter.

If I run my tests with command:

```
mvn clean test
```

In the end of Maven log I get:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.078 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-27T17:11:17+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/322M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project web-test: Exception in provider: java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

This cause the situation, when Allure-reports could not be formed aftet **mvn site** command.

Here is stacktrace of the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project web-test: Exception in provider: java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project web-test: Exception in provider
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Exception in provider
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.assertNoException(SurefirePlugin.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:318)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:892)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Exception in provider
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:87)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1010)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:862)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4RunListener.rethrowAnyTestMechanismFailures(JUnit4RunListener.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:169)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:202)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:82)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.junit.runner.Description.createSuiteDescription(Description.java:123)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener.getSuiteUid(AllureRunListener.java:110)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener.testStarted(AllureRunListener.java:50)
        at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$3.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:115)
        at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:61)
        at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestStarted(RunNotifier.java:112)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.Notifier.fireTestStarted(Notifier.java:100)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.EachTestNotifier.fireTestStarted(EachTestNotifier.java:43)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.startExecutionUnit(JUnitReporter.java:54)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:100)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
        ... 33 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

And here are the contents of the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>m2m-selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
        <allure.version>1.4.23</allure.version>
        <serverAddress>http://site</serverAddress>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin</password>
        <browser>chrome</browser>
        <timeout>500</timeout>
        <!--Selenium driver: remote or local-->
        <seleniumDriver>local</seleniumDriver>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
            <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--NEW-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                        -Dcucumber.options="--plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureReporter"
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                    <!--    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>-->
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <serverAddress>${serverAddress}</serverAddress>
                        <username>${username}</username>
                        <password>${password}</password>
                        <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
                        <browser>${browser}</browser>
                        <timeout>${timeout}</timeout>
                        <seleniumDriver>${seleniumDriver}</seleniumDriver>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!--Needed only to show reports locally. Run jetty:run and
            open localhost:8080 to show the report-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resultsDirectory>allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Could you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1):

It because you messed up with deps and configuration.
First of all, remove allure-junit-adaptor dependency.
And finally remove properties section from surefire configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>m2m-selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>b2b-web-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
        <allure.version>1.4.23</allure.version>
        <serverAddress>http://m2m-b2b/b2b/</serverAddress>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin</password>
        <browser>chrome</browser>
        <timeout>500</timeout>
        <!--Selenium driver: remote or local-->
        <seleniumDriver>local</seleniumDriver>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
            <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--NEW-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                        -Dcucumber.options="--plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureReporter"
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                    <!--    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>-->
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <serverAddress>${serverAddress}</serverAddress>
                        <username>${username}</username>
                        <password>${password}</password>
                        <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
                        <browser>${browser}</browser>
                        <timeout>${timeout}</timeout>
                        <seleniumDriver>${seleniumDriver}</seleniumDriver>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!--Needed only to show reports locally. Run jetty:run and
            open localhost:8080 to show the report-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resultsDirectory>allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: It is quite strange to remove configuration from surefire. But if so, where should I move it instead in this case?

Comment: Allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor since 1.6 uses different interaction mechanism. Now it works as cucumber-jvm plugin instead of junit listener. This so the reason why you should remove listener from surefire configuration.

Comment: Please, could you refactor pom file I've posted in the question description? I have tried to do what you have recommended and it doesn't work. Now I ge t [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project b2b-web-test: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plug
in:2.19.1:test failed: org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener -> [Help 1]

Comment: @SanchelliosProg added fixed pom.xml in my answer

Comment: It should. Submit an issue here please: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cucumberjvm

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the solution is to rename all files inside the project that contains "test" in filename, that are mot a proper .java file.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to answer this ..but I was facing similar issue while executing test cases even if all test cases passed build shows failure with the same exception.

Solution - make sure you don't have any scenario / scenario outline in a feature file with brackets or special characters in some case . Please keep it simple :) hope this helps